How to ensure reproducibility when using pip to control package versions, particularly with cuda?
I am transferring a python venv from the college Linux computer to my own Windows computer with WSL2.
I ran the command on Linux computer:
pip freeze > requirements.txt

to get the same version for reproducibilty so I can pip install those in WSL2.
I used torch with cuda in my project. In the output requirements text, I only got lines like
torch==2.1.2
torchinfo==1.8.0
torchvision==0.16.2

However, I want something like torch==2.1.2+cu121. Is it possible by using pip freeze command.
Also, from the official guide (https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). For stable (2.2.2), Linux, pip, Python, cuda 12.1, I only need to run the command pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio. Why such pip install will ensure I am installing the cuda version.
After running the commmand pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio, I checked the torch and torchvision version in a python enviroment.
>>> import torch
>>> import torchvision
>>> print("Is CUDA available:", torch.cuda.is_available())
Is CUDA available: True
>>> print("Torch version:", torch.__version__)
Torch version: 2.2.2+cu121
>>> print("TorchVision version:", torchvision.__version__)
TorchVision version: 0.17.2+cu121

But I don't want to do it everytime when transferring a venv. Since there are more than one packages needed to check their cuda or cpu version, I think such way (checking in python) is not recommanded. Is there any way to get version detail by pip.

Pytorch packages' version did not contain the buildinfo like cu121 from version 2.0. See https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/. So you can not do that. In case you need this info, you can get the version in one command line like   python3 -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
